# Is there a Visual Studio 2008 keymap profile for Netbeans?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I know there are keymap profiles for Eclipse and Idea that reflect the VS 2k8 key mapping / shortcuts experience quite well, but do you know where I can find one for my IDE of choice, Netbeans?

Could importing from another IDE be possible as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to create my own profile, unluckily there's a key element in VS that prevents this from being completely possible in NetBeans... VS allows you to map the same key to different actions depending on the state of VS (editing, running, running in debug mode, etc.).

That allows you to map, for example, the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to "Build" when editing... and that same <kbd>F5</kbd> key to "Continue" when you hit a breakpoint.

AFAIK this is not possible in NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

No. At the moment in 6.7.1 there are some for Emacs, Eclipse and Idea.

But you can easily map your own and hopefully share this with the community ;-)

You can do so via: Tools->Options->Keymap->Manage Profiles->Duplicate

Then change the duplicated keymap and export it (Manage Profiles)